# OpenCMIS supported ECM

Tags: cmis, opencmis

We are planning to develop an application that can work with any ECM systems. SO we planned to use CMIS.

As our application is in Java, I came across openCMIS. It seemed all useful.

But now I need to know, which all repositories are tested/supported with openCMIS?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCmis will be really helpful for many ecm systems but it is  not a one common answer for all of them. 
For example, for IBM CM or Filenet there is IBM CMIS which comes bundled with Content Navigator. Please note this is also lacking some basic functionalities and i developed that just recently. (on the latest version)

I would recommend to build the java application using the most relevant CMIS apis you need and for the closest specific ECM product.If you want to build it in a way which works on all ECM platforms then the coding needs to be in different way. 
like - identify which ecm system is being called by your  java program
and then load the classes or functions for that specific system.

Hope the above helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This page lists CMIS servers:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html) is one the mostly used CMIS libraries, and I would say it is the most-tested CMIS library you can find.

I have not seen any "official supported list", but OpenCMIS at least works for [Alfresco](http://alfresco.com), [IBM FileNet](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/content-management/filenet-content-manager/), [NemakiWare](http://nemakiware.bitbucket.org), and most CMIS servers I have tried. A notable exception seems to be [IBM Connections](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/lotus/products/connections/), because of [a IBM Connections bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CMIS-593).